# issue pending certificate, not apearing on client

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I am requesting a certificate that must be approved by the CA administrator.

When I make the request, it appears in the CA pending request folder and I right click to issue the certificate. but the approved certificates don’t appear in the personal folder of the requesting computer.

I have tried refreshing the certificates mmc and updating the machine group policies but the certificate does not appear in the client computer.

My question what I need to do after issuing a certificate in order make it appear in the certificate vault of the computer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select top node (Certificates), right-click -> All Tasks -> Automatically Enroll and Retrieve Certificates. Follow certificate enrollment wizard to retrieve and install pending certificate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need your requests number; If you requested your cert using mmc, you'll not know your request number. But you'll find it in the CA Console, during approval or afterwards under "issued certificates".

With this number, you can:

1. certreq -retrieve X" where "X" is your request number
2. A popup appears; select the CA from which you requested your certificate
3. you get back a certificate with your public key from the ca, which you can download to desktop
4. now just import this certificate with mmc under the same user account you've done the request

As result, you should see the imported certificate has attached a key sign on the icon, which means you have a private key for this certificate. If so, you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me:

1. Launch CA mmc
2. Right click CA > Properties
3. Click "Policy Module"
4. Click Properties...
5. Select "Follow the settings in the certificate template, if applicable. Otherwise, automatically issue the certificate."